# .PHP files with .TXT includes (Code Display Error)

Tags: php, include, text-files

So I am using .php pages now to use a .txt include for the navigation.

Here is the live page I am working on : 
http://glustik.com/essex/index.php

It seems to display line 27 code errors, not sure how to get this include to work.

Anyone care to point me in the right direction for this one?

Comment: We'd rather see the code *here* than go looking for it. Paste it into your question.

Comment: paste your current code from line 27 or your question is no worth. you have syntax/typo error for sure.

Comment: Sometimes it is possible to get what a piece of code is doing from looking onto an error text, sometimes it isn't. From the error message 'division by zero' I can tell there might be a division by zero. Please tell us what line 27 looks like, so people can help you further.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Warning: include(txt) [function.include]: failed to open stream: 
No such file or directory in /home/hletf/public_html/essex/index.php on line 27
```

Is your problem already stated there? There is an error since include(txt) is **NOT** a right inclusion of a file. Create your *.txt file first and then include it. Something like `include("foo.txt")`

Comment: Thanks Man, that was it. I did not have the ""'s

Answer (score -3):

If you want files .txt to be parse as .php files you should change your apache configuration, or write your own class which will parse this file and return value that you need

Comment: Im saying that if his apache server is not configured right that his .txt files with php code will not be parsed

Comment: he wanted to include the content, not to parse it as php code. that's what happen when question is not structured good.